# Kafka keeps producing requests even if broker is down

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

Currently when I create producer to send my records and for example for some reasons kafka is not available producer keeps sending the same message indefinitely. How I can stop producing messages for example after I received this error 3 times:

```html
Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I'm using reactor kafka producer:

```java
    @Bean
    public KafkaSender<String, String> createSender() {
        return KafkaSender.create(senderOptions());
    }

    private SenderOptions<String, String> senderOptions() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getClientId());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProducerRetries());
        return SenderOptions.create(props);
    }
```

and then use it to send record:

```java
sender.send(Mono.just(SenderRecord.create(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, null, message), message)))
            .flatMap(result -> {
                if (result.exception() != null) {
                    return Flux.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                        .body(result.exception().getMessage()));
                }
                return Flux.just(ResponseEntity.ok().build());
            })
            .next();
```

Comment: May we have some your code how you produce records? And also, please, share more stack trace

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that your ` props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProducerRetries());` has an effect on producer? How about stack trace on the matter? Or at least more logs...

Comment: I continiously see following message in logs:

  WARN 7468 --- [client] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=mycliet] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

And that's all. That property doesnt change anything

Comment: Any chance that we can have a simple project on GitHub to play with?

Comment: yeap - please check https://github.com/malinovskiy-alex/proxy/

Comment: Kafka is in Docker? Your application is not? You're trying to connect to localhost:9092... Is this all correct?

Comment: it's not correct intentionally. So in case if I send the request to my proxy I'll see error log infinitely

Comment: Where is your app running? I see a Dockerfile there, but are you actually using it, or testing your app outside of Docker first?

Comment: you can start docker compose actually to see how it's woking

Comment: You mean not working? You connected Kafka to Zookeeper, but never your app back to Kafka https://github.com/malinovskiy-alex/proxy/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: yes, this is correct. So I created such environment to be able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the `clusterAndWaitTime = waitOnMetadata(record.topic(), record.partition(), maxBlockTimeMs);` is not involved in the retry and it iterates until `maxBlockTimeMs = 60000` by default. You can decrease this option for the producer via `ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG` property:

```
public static final String MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG = "max.block.ms";
    private static final String MAX_BLOCK_MS_DOC = "The configuration controls how long <code>KafkaProducer.send()</code> and <code>KafkaProducer.partitionsFor()</code> will block."
                                                    + "These methods can be blocked either because the buffer is full or metadata unavailable."
                                                    + "Blocking in the user-supplied serializers or partitioner will not be counted against this timeout.";
```

**UPDATE**

We can fix the problem like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/v1/{topicName}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> postData(
    @PathVariable("topicName") String topicName, String message) {
    return sender.send(Mono.just(SenderRecord.create(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, null, message), message)))
        .flatMap(result -> {
            if (result.exception() != null) {
                sender.close();
                return Flux.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                    .body(result.exception().getMessage()));
            }
            return Flux.just(ResponseEntity.ok().build());
        })
        .next();
}
```

Pay attention to the `sender.close();` in the case of error.

I think it's time to raise an issue against Reactor Kafka project to allow close producer on error.

Comment: So I tried that option. For my case it will throw exception after this timeout:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 1000 ms.

But after that producer still continue sending requests to kafka....

Comment: Consider to use `SenderOptions.stopOnError(true)`. See its Javadocs for more info.

Comment: not sure why, but it still doesn't help... have you tried to reproduce my problem?

Comment: Yes, your test-case is pretty self-explanatory, but it exists after 5 seconds on `Mono.blockingGet()` in the `WebTestClient`, so I don't see anything else.

Comment: After setting this `props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 3000);`, the test fails with an expected error: `Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<400 BAD_REQUEST>`. So, no any retries for the same record.

Comment: unfortunately yes... test case exists correctly but if you start app and try to send real HTTP request you'll see the problem

Comment: Strange. I really get `Failed to update metadata after 3000 ms.` in the REST Client. but at the same time I see that `org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient` tries to get a metadata ignoring my `3000` for `ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG` after that...

Comment: Yeah, I have the same behavior on my side and I'm not really sure how to avoid that..

Comment: OK. There is a `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender` with the loop like `  // main loop, runs until close is called        while (running) {` in its `run()`. So, we need somehow to ensure that `KafkaProducer` is closed when we get an error.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Gotcha, I think Ill raise a ticket there. I dont think your option will work because in case of an error like that I dont receive an exception in flatMap call as it cntiniosly trying to reconnect

Comment: Huh? You get that timeout exception and it is propagated as 400 BAD_REQUEST to response. At least I see that it works for me in your project. However you indeed need to set a `ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG` less than `60000`...

Comment: Ill check it on my end and will let you know

Comment: I checked and yeah, it actually closes my producer and it stops producing request. But I see two issues here:
1. It throws the following exception after I invoke a method close: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread single-1

2. If I close this sender then I can't produce any more messages at all. So I assume I should have one sender per app and don't need to create it on any request. So in case if kafka is down for some reasons I receive error and message won't be put in kafka but if I retry it after some time it should work fine. Do you agree?

Comment: That's correct. I also think that after closing Reactor Kafka should invalidate its `producerMono` and be able to obtain an fresh `KafkaProducer` instance on the next send.

Comment: Created issue - https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/70. Thanks for your help in the investigation.

Comment: please check https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/70#issuecomment-483623412

Answer (score 0):

You can use [circuit breaker pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) for this type of issues but before applying this pattern try to find root cause and it seems that your ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG property is being overridden somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than focus on the error. Fix the problem - it's not connecting to the broker

You're not overriding this in your compose file, so your app is trying to connect to itself

```
bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_URL:localhost:9092}
```

In the compose yml, it appears you forgot this

```
rest-proxy:
   environment:
       KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_URL: kafka:9092
```

Alternatively, if possible, you can use the existing Confluent REST Proxy docker image instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: I want to understand behavior of my app in case of some errors.

Comment: Yes, and you're connecting to the wrong address... So, not sure why this deserves a downvote

Comment: as I know Confluent rest proxy is blocking. I wanted to create non-blocing one.

Comment: because I want to know how to fix that particular problem

Comment: Http requests are generally blocking anyway

Comment: so in my case, I use event loop instead of thread pool which leads to better performance. At least how I understood that:)